# Why Tangent-space normal map is suitable for deforming or animating meshes?

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader

As one of the advantages of Tangent-space normal map (besides few other)  is that using Tangent-space NM, normals of animated or deforming mesh can be accurately calculated which cannot be done using Object-space normal map that means for the deforming faces of the mesh, during deformation there might be a situation where normal direction does not change and tangent direction changes, as a result, bitangent/bi-normal will change too. 
I am trying to understand in which situations this can happen? (i.e. normal directing not changing but tangent direction is changing)

If above is not the case at all, what makes Tangent-space normal map special for deforming meshes which object-space normal map cannot do.

Comment: Maybe I got you wrong, but object space normalmapping does usually not depend on the geometry normal of the mesh. It actually doesn't depend on any geometric property of the mesh. Thus when you deform the mesh, the object space normalmaps will still point in the same direction as before. But this might not be the normal that you want.

Comment: A transformation where the normal remains but the tangent direction changes would be (ampong others) just a rotation around the normal. But as @BDL already pointed out, this is totally irrelevant in this context. An ob ject-space normal map is as wrong when the normal changes as it is when only the tangents change.

Comment: To understand the point that @derhass and BDL mentioned, I wanted to compare both the maps with some face deformation.

I created a setup as shown in the image where 
- mesh at the center is high-poly mesh from which normal maps are baked. 
- mesh on the right has tangent normal map applied.
- mesh on the left has object-space normal map applied
(posting images in a separate comment)
Both looked almost the same. Then I wanted to do a test with deforming faces and upon deforming the faces of the mesh, object-space normal was able to hold the details as tangent-space normal map did.

Comment: Mesh setup:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chayanvinayak/images/master/object-tangent_space_normalMap_01.png

Normal map comparison on deformed meshes: 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chayanvinayak/images/master/object-tangent_space_normalMap_02.png

Comment: That is not a relevant kind of "deformation", it doesn't change the local tangent space in a meaningful way at all.

Comment: - What do you mean by changing local tangent space in a meaningful way? can you give an example?
- Also, as you said that object-space map is as wrong when the normal changes as it is when only tangents change, in this if tangent is not changing in a meaningful way, at least normal is changing significantly?

Comment: it is hard to deduce from the picture what your deformation actually was in a 3D space, but if it did change the normal at all, it did so only very slightly. It is a totally meaningless experiment

Comment: well.. just saying 'meaningless' doesn't explain much